# Are axons of neurosecretory cells in neurohypophysis myelinated?

Tags: neuron

According to the pictures that I found in textbooks and Google [here](https://www.sciencedirect.com/topics/agricultural-and-biological-sciences/posterior-pituitary) these neurons are not myelinated.

I just wanted to be sure. They are not myelinated, are they?[image]